# How to draw Gradients

Tags: graphing-functions

How I can draw the gradients on the tangent to level curves. Shall you give me a hint? For example: $f(x,y) = x^3 - y$ and at points $(0,0)$ $∇f(0,0) = (0,-1)$ . Therefore, How to represent of the gradient whose corresponding constrains ($f(x,y) \leq 0$) are binding at the
points given above $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient as 0 is actually $(0,-1)$. The tangent plane at 0 is going through the origin with slope -1 along the y axis and 0 along the x axis.

Comment: The gradient is $3x^2, -1$ plug 0 into this to get $0,-1$

Comment: true it is my typo